# Error 500 using the Pager Sizes control from xPages Extension library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

When I use the pager sizes control I'm getting a error 500 when I click the "All" link on that control. 10, 25 and 50 work fine.  All throws an error.  Does some other view or db level property need to be set?  It works when I use the Ext Lib Demo db.

Here is my pager panel code:

```
    <xp:panel xp:key="headerPager" id="panel2">
            <xe:pagerSizes id="pagerSizes1" for="viewPanelCurrent"></xe:pagerSizes>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel xp:key="footerPager" id="panel3">
            <xe:pagerSizes id="pagerSizes2" for="viewPanelCurrent"></xe:pagerSizes>
        </xp:panel>
```

Comment: What does the runtime error say? If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Is there anything specific about App you have or viewPanel?

Comment: Okay, more details here. Created a brand new xpages with a single view panel and was able to get the pager size control to work perfectly.   The case I tested originally had that view using the "search in view results" feature.  Basically I'm searching the view to display documents that match the username in a number of fields.  It seems like when this is used the 10,25,50 links still work on the pager size control but not the ALL link.   All link works on a standard view but not when the view is filtered on search results.

Comment: This might be a bug with the pager sizes component. To confirm, create equivalent XPage elements with a data table, data view, and repeat control as your iterators. If the behavior is consistent across all three, it's most likely a bug and should be reported via the project site (extlib.openntf.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you've hit this Shean. This is indeed a bug for which I've logged "PHAN9ECL76" to track this issue.
The XPages Extension Library is now part of the core XPages code and so this issue will be handled by IBM.
The stack trace that I'm seeing states that increasing the HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize variable in notes.ini will overcome this issue. From the tests that I've done this advise does not help, so I suggest that this should be ignored.
So in the meantime and until such time that we fix this issue, avoid using the "All" link. And maybe customise pager sizes property 
 sizes="10 | 25 | 100| 1000"

Comment: Thanks Paul, that works as a workaround.   Where can I track the progress of this issue?

Comment: Where to track this is a good question. By default you don't have access to see the progress of this issue but depending on your support contract you'll have greater access. If and when this issue gets fixed we are likely to publish this in the fix logs

Comment: No problem.  I found a good alternative.  I computed the number of documents in my view and showed that number instead of "ALL" in the pager.  Then I computed the pager display depending on that value so for example 44 docs would show a pager of 10 | 25 | 44, while 88 documents will show 10 | 25 | 50 | 88 and so on.  It gives the user the total value and lets them display that amount.